# Multiple Regression - Converting Standardized Coefficients to Unstandardized

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, standardization

I recently performed a multiple linear regression using a standardized set of data, and I was wondering if it possible to convert the standardized coefficients from the regression into usable unstandardized coefficients. I found and attempted to implement the method found here: https://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/stats1/x92.pdf

but I got significantly different (and very wrong) results compared to what I got using the standardized coefficients and standardized data. All I did was convert each coefficient by multiplying by the ratio of the standard deviations of y and the corresponding x. To calculate the results, I then multiplied each new unstandardized coefficient by each corresponding unstandardized entry in the data set, summed them, and added the intercept (which I believe does not change through the unstandardization process). Is there something I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you handle interaction variables properly?

Comment: I think so. Here is my data and calculations, sorry if it's a bit ugly: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZUDAFnDjf2p21YJPyFHr-_EOnykN-iCAaYTRtIv6PxU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Where did your "Intercept" term come from? The spreadsheet suggests it is the constant term in a regression involving the standardized variables--but in that case it should have been zero rather than $-2.45$. To make progress on this question we really need to see the calculations you made to standardize the data and to perform the regression.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say a model is: $y=1+x+xz+z^3$, and $\sigma_y,\sigma_x,\sigma_z$ - standard deviations of variables. You would transform the equation like follows: $Y=\sigma_y+\frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}X+\frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x\sigma_z}XZ+\frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_z^3}Z^3$

Comment: I believe that's what I did. My calculations are in the comment link above.